1093 error is coming while writing an sql query, requesting assistance
I created a table which has duplicates and to remove them i used the below query
DELETE FROM shipping_dimension
WHERE id NOT IN (
    SELECT MIN(id)
    FROM shipping_dimension
    GROUP BY ship,vehicle_company,toll_required,id
);

I am getting error:1093 saying "you can't specify target_table 'shipping _dimesion'for update in from clause

Please tag the RDBMS (sql server, oracle ...) you are using

Are you sure you really want the id be part of the GROUP BY clause of your subquery?

Note that window functions are probably faster here.
